# Can I pragmatically populate a UITableView from CoreData?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am used to fetch from `CoreData` exactly what I need and populate my `UITableView` accordingly.

Now I am faced with a new scenario. I have a `News Feed` that is shown to the user as a `UITableView`. because the `News Feed` will be have lots of previous data I was wondering *if I could somehow* set up `CoreData`  so that I can fetch the `row` as the `Cell` becomes visible in my `UITableView`.

I do not know if that is possible given that I need to give a total number of rows in `numberOfRowInsection` and having lets say `1000` would overkill my memory?? or I do not put a total number and there is a dynamic way of doing that?

Basically what I wonder if it is possible to fetch from `CoreData` as the `Cell` becomes visible? mainly I am puzzled on what do you put on `numberOfRowInsection`?

Could anyone give me an example of the fetch would look like & how to populate into `UITableView` or a link to a resource that explains exactly that(I cant find any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage your News Feeds. It handles the fetch from your database and updates your `UITableView` while scrolling.

- A Tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller
- Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html